# Fitting a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions

I'm investigating a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ which satisfies the following properties:

1. $f(1,n)=n^2-n-1$
2. $f(2,n)=n^2-5$
3. $f(n-1,n)=n^2-2n+1$
4. $f(n^2,2n)=n^2$

I'd like to find a closed form for $f(m,n)$, or at least a few possibilities.  I understand that the given information is not nearly enough to determine a closed form, so we'd have to assume a thing or two about $f(m,n)$, like it is quadratic in $n$.  How would I go about finding potential fits for my function?  Is there a tool on the internet that allows me to plot points $(m,n,f(m,n))$ to determine possible formulas?  I've tried OEIS, but can't seem to find anything helpful.

Comment: Where did this come from?

Comment: @Ethan: It comes from the dimension of a projective variety defined by two integer parameters $(m,n)$.  The variety is rather complicated, but is kind of like a Grassmannian.  If this were a Grassmannian, we would have $f(m,n)=n(n-m)$.